# VSCode always runs python interpreter in WSL

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I selected the windows python interpreter in the top-left section of vscode:
[image]

Nonetheless, if I press the run-button on the top-right, a new WSL-Terminal is spawned trying to execute the windows interpreter.

I have the WSL for VSCode Extension installed, but it is not active (as I do not want to run the code using WSL):
[image]

Watching the terminal, one can see that the windows interpreter path I preiviously set is tried to be executed by WSL (as this last screenshot shows a bash-prompt) - how can I set this to run with Windows?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is the case because the setting `terminal.integrated.shell.windows` in the users `settings.json` was refering to WSL - I was not aware the setting existed before, so lesson learned, I guess.

fix:
`"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "cmd.exe"`